# Checking Quotient of Numpy array by adding one array element at a time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a np.array of numbers. I am wanting the user to give the program a number, and it will return which of the numbers in the array divided by the sum of the array are be greater than or equal to the number given by the user. Just from left to right, not every possible condition

Example:

```
x= np.array [1,2,3,4,5]
userNum = input (“Enter a number: ”)

#code. Say the user inputs 5. The sum of array = 15. Start at 1/15. Go until
#Quotient is >= userNum. In this case, it would have to go through 3 times
#(1+2+3 = 6). Then, output the numbers it had to calculate. (output: [1 2 3]
```

A while loop? Is there a way to user np.cumsum? I thought of while loop running like this:

```
Denom = (x[1]/sum(x))
#Start with dividing the first number
while Denom <= userNum
    #psuedocode:
    #(x[1]/sum(x)) doesn't work
    #Add the next element of the array to the one(s) already added
    #Denom is updated to (x[1]+x[2])/sum(x). This will continue to
    #(x1[1]+x[2]+...x[n]>=userNum
    #Store the numbers used in a seperate array
print 'Here are the numbers used: ' #Numbers used from array to be larger than userNum
                    #ex: [1 2 3]
```

Not sure how to implement it. Help?

Comment: Why would you involve a quotient in any of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(x[0:np.flatnonzero(x.cumsum()>userNum)[0]+1])
```

This should give you the numbers used.

Input:

```
x = np.array([3,1,2,4,5])
userNum = 7
print(x[0:np.flatnonzero(x.cumsum()>userNum)[0]+1])
```

Output:

```
[3 1 2 4]
```

A little explanation: `x.cumsum()`returns cumulative sum, and `x.cumsum()>userNum` returns a numpy array indicating whether the condition is true for each index of the array. In the example I posted above, it `x.cumsum()` returns `[3, 4, 6, 10, 15]` and `x.cumsum()>userNum` returns `[False, False, False, True, True]`. `np.flatnonzero` returns the index of nonzeros elements in an array. In this case it returns the indexes of `True` in the array. You need to find the index of the first `True` in the array because that is the index of the last number used. At last you print out the numbers used from `0` to `np.flatnonzero(x.cumsum()>userNum)[0]`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
x[x.cumsum()<=5]
```

I don't understand the goal of the sum.